# DFP ad in colorbox, empty ad is showing

Tags: 7, javascript, advertising

I am showing Google DFP ad in colorbox, I am using setCollapseEmptyDiv(true); to collapse empty divs, but in colorbox, ad collapsed but blank color box remains there.
I have tried several ways to hide it but didn't worked. I have checked display:none by jquery, like that:

> if( $("#ad_id").css("display") == "none"){           $.colorbox.remove(); }

but before the ad loads, color box shows up, so it cant find display:none.
Then I have used **setTimeout** to check condition (display:none) repetitively, this worked but still colorbox appears for at least 2 seconds before disappear.
So how to hold colorbox to load until that display:none condition check?
Give me some direction.